# regex to find and replace deleting/changing non-targeted text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
text text (numbers) text
text text with some punctuation
word ({ numbers }) word ({ numbers}} word ({...
text text (numbers) text
text text with some punctuation
word ({ numbers }) word ({ numbers}} word ({...
...
```

So every third line is `word ({ numbers }} ...`
and I want to delimit all of the third lines to look like

word | ({ numbers }) | word | ({ numbers}} | word | ({...

I am using notepad++ and using find and replace regex patterns:

Find : `(\(\{.+?\}\))`
Replace : `| $1 |`

and it seems to work, except there is a problem.
After I do the find and replace and I scroll through the document to see that everything looks ok I notice that after 7 thousand lines in some places there is a black square with white letters inside, the letters are LF and the whole document gets messed up.

Any idea as to why this happens and how to fix it?

I realized that the regex works perfectly for 7,514 lines, but after that it messes everything up. But I do not notice anything about that line specifically which might mess things up. Could there be a size limit on replace all in notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I well understand your need, but is this working for you?

Find what: `(\(\{.+?\}\))`
Replace with: `| $1 |`

Make sure that `Regular expression` is checked and click on `Replace All`.

Comment: You're answer works, as does mine (I think). I just tried what you suggest but still, after I click on replace all there are characters inserted like i describe above. The characters are black squares with white letters, LF, inside the black square. I posted a screen shot but i need 10 reputation to post an image.

Comment: In general the file gets very messed up after 7514 lines

Comment: @jeremREE: These characters appear when you've selected `display line break character`. Sorry I haven't an english version of NPP and I can't tell you the proper name of the menu, but I think it is 'Display > Special symbol > Display line beak'.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did this and now I see at the end of every line [LF] . But do you know why this is inserted into the middle of the line and in general why the whole order of characters are changed/deleted from the regex you gave?